# How to retain Intellisense for a custom type in PhpStorm when requiring another module?

Tags: typescript, jestjs, phpstorm, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

Why does Intellisense disappear after requiring a value from another module for a Jest custom matcher?

```
const foo = require('./foo'); // returns string 'foo'

/**
 * @typedef {jest.Expect} expect
 * @property {Function} toEqualFoo
 */
expect.extend({
  toEqualFoo(received) {
    const pass = received === foo;

    return {
      pass,
      message: () => `expected ${received} to equal foo`
    }
  }
});
```

[image]

Only if I remove the 'require' statement and hardcode `const pass = received === 'foo';`, does the intellisense work.

[image]

Am I missing something?